# Django Hide Processing Page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a generic set up where you take an assessment which kicks you to a processing page which massages the data, stores it, and then funnels you to the correct output page.  You never actually see the processing page it runs and sorts you to the results.  I'm concerned this could be exploited.  Is there a way to hide this completely without losing my flexibility?

Current flow
Question_Page -> Processing Page -> Output Page (depends upon what you took as determined by the processing page)

I'd like to keep this as some sort of function within a view if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the flow would look more like:
Question_Page -> Post Data View (processes the data from the question page) -> redirect to Output page (based upon data results).

The only page someone would "see" is the "Question Page" and "Output page"... now if processing takes a long time, they could click submit again on the "Question Page". There are lots of ways to deal with that in javascript.

Comment: The reason I ask the question is I was crawled and it hit that processing page.  I'm wondering if that is a potential security hole.

Comment: no more than any other form posting data; you need to be careful how you use the data (i believe django does alot inside its form `clean` methods) but should still think about how each piece of data is used.

Comment: Good point.  I'm using the ORM so it should be validated against protected characters.....but maybe I'll add in another check just to be safe.